# IBM Cloud start pack does not recognize java8

Tags: java, ibm-cloud

I've created a new project from a start pack in IBM Cloud and I've created a toolchain for it. But when I commit new code to git, my build stage fails with this message

[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 1.7.0 is not in the allowed range [1.8,).

How do I force IBM Cloud to use Java8?

I am little bit surprised because IBM Cloud liberty profile actually uses java8, according to this

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/customizingJRE.html#customizing_jre

Comment: Which java version (source and target) have you specified in your pom file?

Comment: There's no explicit java version specified in the pom file. It's generated by IBM Cloud.

Comment: Did you try to set  it explicitly to java 8?

Comment: I've tried adding <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> with no success